# How to reset the timecode whenever pressing record button on Sony nxcam?

Tags: sony, camera

The time displayed on LCD on my Sony nxcam has counted up and up. I'm sorry if this is a silly question. But is it possible to reset the timecode every time I press the record button automatically?
I go in to setting and find the TC/UB settings, I almost tried everything, But what I need is probably not an option, Right?

My camera model is "Sony HXR-NX100"

Comment: Please add the exact camera model.